# Discord JDA OnReady doesn't work

Tags: java, discord

I am creating a bot for Discord using JDA (Java). I am facing a problem while trying to simple debug message on java console.
I want to print "Bot running" but doesn't work . It doesn't print.

The problem is in the onReady(), please see the code.

```
public class MessageListener extends ListenerAdapter
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
        throws LoginException, RateLimitedException, InterruptedException
   {
     JDA jda = new  JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken("x").buildBlocking();
    jda.addEventListener(new MessageListener());
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event)
{
    if (event.isFromType(ChannelType.PRIVATE))
    {
        System.out.printf("[PM] %s: %s\n", event.getAuthor().getName(),
                                event.getMessage().getContent());
    }
}
@Override
public void onReady(ReadyEvent e){

            String server = "bot running\n";
            System.out.println(server);
    }   
}
```

EDIT:
Code updated
Sry I messed up the code, but "OnReady" doesn't work. It should work when the bot is loaded

Comment: Where do you call `ReadyListener`? Please provide a Minimum, Complete, Verifiable, Example for better answers - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sry I messed up the code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are adding the Listener after the Bot started. When you call buildBlocking on the jda the Bot starts and blocks this Thread. So the listener gets never Added.

```
JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT);
builder.setToken("x");
builder.addEventListener(new MessageListener());
JDA jda = builder.buildBlocking();
```

Comment: You should edit this into your answer. Answers (and questions) should be standalone without reading the comments; you may also have noticed that comments aren't really suited for blocks of code.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.